# Opencv Video Processing in Swift 2

Tags: opencv, swift2, video-processing

I am trying to create a video processing application in swift 2 using opencv. 
I opened in video mode and my capture mode is in kcvpixelformattype_32bgra  format.then i convert it into a UIimage and pass to a opencv.
After converting to MAT , am getting a black image.